# White MacBook battery in aluminium MacBook

Tags: macbook, battery

I have a MacBook aluminium (not pro, but the MacBook late 2008 model). Battery is harder to find, perhaps because it's a rare model. I'm wondering whether I can use a white MacBook battery? Or a MBP 13' battery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can purchase the battery [here](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB771LL/A). According to [this](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MA561LL/A?fnode=MTY1NDA2Nw&mco=MTA4NzUwMzg), The white battery is only compatible with the white bodied macbook.

Comment: Sure, I could have purchased it there if I was living in US. :) I eventually found an aluminium battery, but the Apple store in my city (Beijing) didn't have it. Thanks anyway. :)